# How can I add Angular component html in existing app?

Tags: angular, angular7

I want to apply angular components

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'
import { DialogService } from './dialog/dialog.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: '<div></div>',
})
export class AppComponent {
  dialogs: any;
  constructor(public dialogService: DialogService) {
       dialogs = dialogService.getDialogs();

       // dialogs are like following = 
       //   { "id": 1, "name": "D1", component: "<x-component>…</x-component>" },
  }
}
```

dialog service gets JSON data that includes a component html. How can I add this (`<x-component>`) component on an existing component?

Answer (score 0):

assign returned component from JSON to a variable
`this.returnedComponent = myComponent`

then in your HTML put

`<div [innerHtml]="returnedComponent"></div>`